# Setup icon correctly in IntelliJ so that is gets compiled with program (to jar)

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, icons, embedded-resource

I've been learning Java at my university and the programs we made as homework assignments are quite nice. But I've been playing around with some extra features to learn more. I've created a GUI for a program using Swing and AWT. I've added an icon to the `JFrame` and when I run the the program in IntelliJ the icon is there. But when I try to compile the program into a JAR file the icon doesn't get compiled with it for some reason.. Is there a way to make this work?

The way I've currently set it up is as follows:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("resources/icon.png");
```

This is how I've declared the image which is in the resources map of my project, I've marked this resources folder as a resources folder in the project structure under modules.

Then I set the icon as following:

```
frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
```

The name of my `JFrame` is `frame`, this all works when running the program within IntelliJ but when I make a jar file it doesn't seem to be able to use the icon ;/

Does someone know how to fix this? I really like to learn from it so some extra explanation would be really nice!!

Comment: For starters, the `String` based argument to an `ImageIcon` constructor is presumed to be a `File` path so won't work for an [tag:embedded-resource]. See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now and learned some new stuff ;) How can I mark this answered?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. *"How can I mark this answered?"* There should be a button on the page with words to the effect 'Answer my own question' click it and.. go from there.